# Issue while running a fragment template android app

Tags: android-studio

i tried to design a app in android studio while creating a fragment template app at time of creating project it generated two java files one for main activity and one for MainFragmentActivity now  i wrote the java code of the fragment in MainFragmentActivity.java file and i run the app . when i run it i realized that Functions in MainFragmentActivity.java file are not executed. how to make those functions to run i mean how to connect the mainactivity.java file and MainFragmentActivity.java file.
I am a beginner. please help thanks in advance :)

Comment: keep your question precise and share code snippet to get quicker response. Point out in the shared code, where exactly the problem is.

Comment: Share the code here, We need atleast to see how your MainActivity is implementing the fragment.